# gearbox or just bearing

Tags: ford, manual-transmission, shifting, transit

Hi All before going ahead and buying another gear box and clutch kit some advice may help. I have a mk7 ford transit with a 6 speed box I had never had a problem with getting into gear But had a grinding noise from all backward gears when driving  Then it move to all gears except 3rd were it was quite well I stop one day and it would not come out of gear so maybe it will just be thrust bearing not gearbox what do you think

Comment: You have more than 1 reverse gear? which box is that then? If you have the Duratorq 2.2 then is it likely to be the MMT6 manual transmission or derivative?

Comment: did not say reverse gear I said the backward gears 2nd,4th,and 6th It is a 2.4 140  RWD

Comment: Ie forward and backward then? Sounds like the Italian lorries in the war, 1 forward gear and 4 reverse...